# How to solve this, with law of indices?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$4^x+4^2=4^{(x+2)}$$ I tried to substitute with $u$: $$u=4^x$$ But I have no idea what to do after I get $$ u+4^2=4^{(x+2)}$$

Comment: Use that $\,x^{a} \cdot x^{b}=x^{a+b}\,$.

Comment: Write $4^{x+2}$ in terms of $u$, too.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so that will just be $$u*4^2$$ ?

Comment: Yes. Now you want to solve $u+4^2=u\cdot 4^2$. And $4^2=16$.

Comment: So, I got u= 16/15, -> $$4^x=16/15$$ and then no idea how to find x @ThomasAndrews

Comment: How do you solve $a^x=b$ in general?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews haven't encountered questions like that before, so no idea :/

Comment: Tried to do base log of 4 x =16/15, but didn't get closer to the solution

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$
4^{x+2} =4^2 \cdot 4^x= 4^2 \cdot u
$$
so you have
$$
u+4^2=4^2 \cdot u
$$
solve for $u$ than use logarithms.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply prove that, by writing it down as:
$$u+4^2=4^2 \cdot u$$
$$u+16=16u$$
$$u=16u-16$$
$$-15u=-16\implies u=\frac{16}{15} \implies 4^x=\frac{16}{15}$$
Now, we use $\ln$ to find the value of $x$:
$$\ln(4^x)=\ln(\frac{16}{15})\implies x\cdot \ln(2^2) = \ln(\frac{16}{15})$$
$$2x\ln(2)=\ln(\frac{16}{15})\tag1$$
$$(1)\implies x=\frac{\ln(\frac{16}{15})}{2\ln(2)} = 2−\frac{\log(15)}{2\log2}$$

From here, you can easily calculate the exact value of $x$:

$$x\approx 0.04655$$

Comment: Of course $\ln(16/15)-=4\ln 2-\ln(15)$, so you can rewrite that result as $$2-\frac{\log 15}{2\log 2}$$

Comment: Ahh, okay now it makes sense, thank you :)